# Force all coefficients to be negative in PROC REG

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm wondering if there's a way to force all non-intercept coefficients to be positive/negative in proc reg. If I use:

```
model depvar=indvar;
RESTRICT indvar<0;
```

Then I always get a syntax error. Looks like Proc reg only supports equations and not inequalities? I'm just wondering if there's any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Direct from the source: [Can I apply an inequality constraint to the parameters in PROC REG?](http://support.sas.com/kb/22/636.html)

In short: no, but you can with PROC NLIN (nonlinear regression) with the BOUNDS statement.